# String array variable not getting value from Excel sheet's cell and giving output as null

Tags: excel

I am new to java programming & selenium and learning the Jxl concepts with jxl-2.6.12.jar file. I am getting the error in the following code when trying to assign the value from the excel sheet's cell to String array variable. String array variable value comes as null and it results in NULLpointerException Error.

Problem in code is:::::

```
    if ( sht[0].getCell(3, rowIteration).getContents()  == "Y")
                        { arrString[arrIndex] = sht[0].getCell(1, rowIteration).getContents();
                         System.out.println(arrString[arrIndex]);
       }
```

Complete Code is::::::

```
        package excellearning;

        import java.io.File;
        import java.io.IOException;

        import jxl.Cell;
        import jxl.Sheet;
        import jxl.Workbook;
        import jxl.read.biff.BiffException;





        public class ExcelLearning {

            ExcelLearning xl = new ExcelLearning();

            public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException,BiffException {
                //ExcelLearning xlObject = new ExcelLearning();
                xlLearning();


            }
```

Method 1:::::

```
public static void xlLearning() throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException, BiffException, IOException {

                    Sheet sht[] = null;
                    String[] arrString = new String[20];
                    sht = get_Data_From_Excel();
                    Cell baseRowCell, dataRowCell;
                    int rowCount =  sht[0].getRows();
                    int colCount = sht[0].getColumns();
                    System.out.println (rowCount + " " + colCount);
                    boolean flag = false;
                    int colIteration = 0 , rowIteration = 1, arrIndex = 0;
                    //String str=null;


                while(rowIteration < rowCount)  
                {   

                    if ( sht[0].getCell(3, rowIteration).getContents()  == "Y")
                        { arrString[arrIndex] = sht[0].getCell(1, rowIteration).getContents();
                         System.out.println(arrString[arrIndex]);
                    }
                     rowIteration++;
                     arrIndex ++;
                }

                int length = arrString.length;

                                        for(arrIndex=0; arrIndex<length; arrIndex++)
                                            {
                                            System.out.println(arrString[arrIndex].toString());
                                            }





        }
```

Method 2:::::

```
public static Sheet[] get_Data_From_Excel()throws BiffException, IOException
            {      Workbook wrk1;
                   Sheet sheet1[] = null;
                    try {


                        wrk1 =  Workbook.getWorkbook(new File("D:/Mercury_Master.xls"));

                        sheet1 = wrk1.getSheets();
                   } catch (BiffException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    return sheet1;

                }

        }
```

Can you please let me know why its happening as I unable to find the root cause?

This is the sheet's screen shot:::

Comment: In case of NullPointerException, the exact line is most important. It means that in this line one of the objects that a method is called on is null. If you want help on an NPE you have to paste the stack trace with the line number and the line with a bit of context (which you did) and a note which line exactly corresponds to the line in the stack trace (by line number, which you didn't).

Comment: This is the stack::Thread [main] (Suspended (exception NullPointerException)) 
 ExcelLearning.xlLearning() line: 66 
 ExcelLearning.main(String[]) line: 21     and line of code for the same is ::::: System.out.println(arrString[arrIndex].toString());

Answer (score 0):

`sht[0].getCell(1, rowIteration).getContents()` can return null. In those cases, `arrString[arrIndex]` will also be null. You can set it to an empty String in those cases or explicitly check for null before doing anything with it.

If it is null this code will throw an NPE:
`System.out.println(arrString[arrIndex].toString());`

while this code should be fine:
`System.out.println(arrString[arrIndex]);` and simply print null.